# UITableViewCell Custom (stretching) Background Using UIAppearance

Tags: ios, uitableview, background

I'm trying to cusotmize UITableViewCell through UIAppearance in the same way I implemented a custom UINavigationBar (ruby motion syntax):

```
bg = UIImage.imageNamed("cell_bg.png").resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,13,0,13))
UITableViewCell.appearance.setBackgroundImage(bg, forState:UIControlStateNormal, barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

but setBackgroundImage isn't defined, nor is setBackgroundView nor setBackgroundViewImage... UITableViewCell conforms to UIAppearanceContainer and so shouldn't I be able to use one of these?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforming to UIAppearanceContainer doesn't mean that you can set the appearance of anything you like, it just means that it will offer an appearance proxy. There aren't any built-in UIAppearance methods for UITableViewCell as far as I know.

For your needs, try creating a UIImageView with your stretchable image, and setting it as the `backgroundView` of the cell.

Comment: Works exactly as I'd hoped. Thank you!